# Round date in the Array and delete before item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have an array of `DateTime` objects like:

```
a = [
 [Tue, 05 Mar 2013],
 [Tue, 12 Mar 2013],
 [Tue, 19 Mar 2013],
 [Tue, 26 Mar 2013],
 [Tue, 02 Apr 2013],
 [Tue, 09 Apr 2013]
]
```

where `a[0]` is a `Date` object. I need to search for a specific date, like:

```
a.index('Tue, 06 Mar 2013'.to_date)
```

to find its index and delete everything before (and in another case after) this item. I need to search by any date, like in the example above, I'm searching by `Tue, 05 Mar 2013`, so it should be rounded to the nearest value: `Tue, 05 Mar 2013`. How could it be done in a Ruby way?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: for now, only a.index('Tue, 06 Mar 2013'.to_date) - but this works only when I have specific date, existent in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using dates, should be easier to use timestamps:

```
'Tue, 06 Mar 2013'.to_time.to_i
 => 1362528000
```

Higher the value, more in the future this date is.

If you are not inserting items in your list frequently, every time you insert a new item, sort it. When you find the index for the date , remove all other items. For example:

```
# Your dates list converted to timestamps
> times 
 => [1362441600, 1363046400, 1363651200, 1364256000, 1364860800, 1365465600] 
# Find the timestamp equal or greater than the given date
> correct_index_val = times.find{|x| x <= 'Tue, 27 Mar 2013'.to_time.to_i}
 => 1362441600 # this is actually the position for 26 Mar
# Position of the value equal or greater than the given date
> times.index(correct_index_val)
 => 3
# cutting the array in that point
> times[idx..-1]
 => [1364256000, 1364860800, 1365465600]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way :

> ***I need to search it for specific date.***

```
require 'date'

a = [
 ['Tue, 05 Mar 2013'],
 ['Tue, 12 Mar 2013'],
 ['Tue, 19 Mar 2013'],
 ['Tue, 26 Mar 2013'],
 ['Tue, 02 Apr 2013'],
 ['Tue, 09 Apr 2013']
]

nwar = a.flatten.map{|d| Date.parse(d)}
# point free style is - a.flatten.map(&Date.method(:parse))
srchdt = Date.parse('Tue, 06 Mar 2013')
p nwar.index(srchdt) # => nil
srchdt = Date.parse('Tue, 26 Mar 2013')
p nwar.index(srchdt) # => 3
```

> ***After we have index of the item, I need to delete everything before (another case is to delete after) this item.***

```
ind = nwar.index(srchdt) # => 3
nwar.shift(ind)
p nwar.map(&:to_s) # => ["2013-03-26", "2013-04-02", "2013-04-09"]
```